# Uninstall Sharepoint Infrastructure Update

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

I installed WSS Infrastructure Update and MOSS Infrastructure Update (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepointserver/bb735839.aspx) and now I can't restore the content database on an older version. Do you know if there is a way to uninstall it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no supported methods to uninstall updates in MOSS or WSS.  Your only option is to restore a backup, which is why you should always back up everything and test the integrity of the backup before installing updates.

Answer (score 1):

The only option that I can think of is to restore the backup on another machine that has the same level of updates as when the backup was done, upgrade the whole box to Infrastructure Update, backup this environment and restore it in your already-upgraded-environment.

Comment: I second Sacha's recommendation. This is the way to save yourself in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such an option, as others pointed out, the only option is to restore from a backup.

When you are trying to restore a content database to a different box both should have the same set of updates installed, otherwise you might experience all kind of problems.